# Windows batch file - check if file has been modified

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm configuring a windows machine to continuously run a powerpoint presentation.  The ppt file is located on a samba share (windows file sharing) and will be updated periodically.  I need a way to make a batch file that will restart the ppt slide show if the file has been changed.  The batch script will run on a a regular interval, and will hopefully check to see if the file has been updated, and re-start the slideshow if it has.

If there is a way to do this in powershell, that would work too.

Answer (score 6):

Well, in a batch, the easiest way I would think of would be to periodically check whether the file's last modification date and/or its size has changed.

You can get both via the following:

```
for %%X in (myfile) do set size=%%~zX&set filetime=%%~tX
```

You can then cache those values and compare whether they have changed since the last iteration. Using a delay (a few seconds maybe) via

```
ping -n 11 localhost >nul 2>nul
```

(for 10 seconds delay) can help in not checking too often.

So, it might look a little like the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set FileName=MyPresentation.pptx
set FileTime=-
:loop
for %%X in (%FileName%) do (
    if %FileTime% NEQ %%~tX (
        rem just an example
        taskkill /f powerpnt.exe
        start %FileName%
    )
    set FileTime=%%~tX
)
rem wait 5 seconds before checking again
ping -n 6 localhost >nul 2>nul
goto :loop
```

In PowerShell the code wouldn't look too different, except that you get to the relevant properties a little easier:

```
$FileName = "MyPresentation.pptx"
$FileTime = Get-Date

# endless loop
for () {
    $file = Get-Item $FileName
    if ($FileTime -ne $file.LastWriteTime) {
        Get-Process powerpnt* | Stop-Process
        Invoke-Item $file
    }
    $FileTime = $file.LastWriteTime
    Start-Sleep 5
}
```

Comment: I was getting "08:29 was unexpected at this time." I got it to work by adding double-quotes around all instances of "%%~tX".

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below. It checks for the current time and checks when the file was last modified. If the two values are the same it is assumed the file was altered.

```
@echo off &setlocal

TITLE File Monitor

Set file=Test.txt

:CheckforAlter
Set modif_time=
Set allm=

cls
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:,. " %%A in ("%time%") do (
  set "Hour=%%A"
  set "Min=%%B"
  set "Sec=%%C"
)

set /a Hour = Hour %% 12
if %Hour%==0 set "Hour=12"

set "Allm=%Hour%:%Min%:%Sec%"

for /f %%i in ('"forfiles /m %file% /c "cmd /c echo @ftime" "') do set modif_time=%%i
echo.
echo.
IF %modif_time%==%Allm% (
echo File was altered.
start "" "%file%"
Timeout /t 1 >nul
)
echo file wasn't modified.
GOTO CheckforAlter
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

```
@echo off
if not "%~1"=="" echo Modified date of %~1 is %~t1
```

on [Experts exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/MS_DOS/Q_21603646.html). Maybe a good point to start from.

Comment: Oooh, linking to the evil hyphen site. Now that's probably frowned upon here :-)

Comment: was'nt aware of that. trying to downvote myself for this... ;)

Comment: Well, since Stack Overflow set out to destroy the evil hyphen site, I just figured so :-). No need to downvote, unless others think it's unhelpful :-)

Comment: @Joey: SO wasn't set out to destroy EX, but be better. Sooo much better. And it accomplished it's goal. EX will implode by itself.